SAS Kaplan Meier how do I get the results to show together?
I am looking at a copy number of various genes to survival time. I want to see the genes individually and if two or more genes together are different. The picture of the dataset is attached.
The problem is the Kaplan Meier curve is giving a ton of individual graphs and not together.
'''
ods graphics on;
proc lifetest data=Ztoall_numeric plots=survival(strata=individual);
time SurvivalMonths_num* Event(0);
strata GFPT2_num GFPT1_num NAGK_num GNPNAT1_num PGM3_num UAP1_num OGT_num OGA_num MGAT1_num;
run; 

'''





Your strata variables are continuous.  The SAS documentation describes shows how to specify the ranges for categories on the STRATA statement.  https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/statug/statug_lifetest_syntax05.htm
